# Oracle:inner join between file and table

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm new to oracle and plsql, so just bear with me.
I have a file `TYPES.txt`,

```
id,name,values
1,aaa,32
2,bbb,23
3,cvv,12
4,fff,54
```

I also have a table in my db, `PARTS.ATTRIBUTES`

```
id,name,props,crops
1,aaa,100,zzzz
2,bbb,200,yyyy
3,cvv,300,xxxx
4,fff,400,wwww
5,sasa,343,gfgg
6,uyuy,897,hhdf
```

I'd like to do an `INNER JOIN` on the file `TYPES` and `ATTRIBUTES` based on the column `name`. Now, i have done this by initially loading file `TYPES` into a temp table and then doing `INNER JOIN` between the temp table and `ATTRIBUTES` table.

**But i'd like to know whether it is possible to do INNER JOIN between `TYPES` file and `ATTRIBUTES` table without making use of a temp table.**

I understand that i can load the file using and get respective rows using following script:

```
declare
 file utl_file.file_type;
 line varchar2(500);
begin
 file :=utl_file.fopen('USER_DIR','TYPES.txt','r');
loop
 utl_file.get_line(file ,line);
 dbms_output.put_line(line);
end loop;
exception
 when others then
utl_file.fclose(file);
end;
```

Could someone be kind enough to explain to me how i can do the join between file contents and the db table?

P.S. The file `TYPES.txt` is dynamically generated and can have different number of columns at different times.

Comment: `External Tables` is something which you are looking for. Map your file on server to a table using external table. Read here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cleaner approach is   to use an `EXTERNAL TABLE`.

Use a create statement like this to create `TYPES_external` table.

```
CREATE TABLE TYPES_external (
  id      NUMBER(5),
  name    VARCHAR2(50),
  Values  VARCHAR2(50)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY USER_DIR
  ACCESS PARAMETERS (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
    (
  id      NUMBER(5),
  name    VARCHAR2(50),
  Values  VARCHAR2(50)
    )
  )
  LOCATION ('TYPES.txt','TYPES.txt')
)
PARALLEL 5
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

Once created , you can use this external table(`TYPES_external`) just as you 
use any database table for `select` operation.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but might i presume that this external table can be executed from within an oracle procedure? You see `TYPES.txt` is a dynamically generated file and so can have n number of columns at a time.

Comment: @Nathaniel : Yes.  You could use `execute immediate` statement to create the table dynamically with your parameters inside procedure. be careful about the quotes. You can google for some examples.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. One thing i'd like to ask, is there any other way, do the merge without using a temp table at all.`What i mean to ask is, whether or not it is possible to do the merge directly between the file and the table? `